# Is there a way to deploy a rails app that uses sqlite on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have developed a Ruby on Rails application with the default Sqlite database. When I deployed it on Heroku, some of the pages are not loading.

Comment: You won't be able to use SQLite on Heroku. The filesystem is ephemeral - all your data will disappear at random. Use their Postgres solutions.

Comment: Postrges only or youll have a lot of headaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other posters are correct in that you cannot use SQLite on Heroku, but I wanted to spend a minute to specify WHY this is true.

Heroku enforces best practices on the platform. What this means is that they take a very opinionated stance on deployment, and force you to write code in such a way that deploying it scalably becomes simpler.

One of the ways they do this is by treating your webserver(s) as ephemeral: any data they write to the disk on the running dyno can be destroyed at any moment.

This design decision forces you (the developer of the application) to store files that your application needs in a safer, faster, dedicated file storage service (like Amazon S3). This practice results in a lot of scalability benefits:

- If your webservers don't need to write to disk, they can be deployed many many times without worrying about storage constraints.
- No disks need to be shared across webservers. Sharing disks typically causes IO contention and can adversely affect performance.
- It makes it easy to scale your web application horizontally across commodity servers, since disk resources aren't required.

So, the reason why you cannot use SQLite on Heroku is because SQLite stores all database information in a file on disk, and because Heroku will delete the files on your disk, this won't work.

That is why it is recommended to use a 'real' database server like Postgres or MySQL, because they are hosted separately, and have their own storage / etc.

If you *really* wanted to use SQLite on Heroku, you could always host your SQLite database on a separate server (outside Heroku), and then connect to that database over the internet. But this isn't really recommended, especially since SQLite was not really designed for this pattern of usage.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SQLite with Heroku. They require the use of Postgres. [Here is a good tutorial that walks you through the switch from SQLite to Postgres](http://www.daveferrara1.com/ruby-in-rails-switch-from-sqlite3-to-postgres/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot to use sqlite in Heroku. Simple solution is specifying gems.

**Gemfile:**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do 
  gem 'pg' #PostgreSQL
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the 'pg' gem for production

```
 group :production do
   gem 'pg'
 end
```

You can still use `sqlite` in development if you'd like

```
 group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
 end
```

Heroku has postgres pre-installed on the server. You could use sqlite but you'd have to install it yourself. This is easier.